# Google Share button provokes Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'

Tags: javascript, google-api, console, google-plus, share-button

Using a simple implementation of [Google's share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) I'm getting the following message:

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://accounts.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://mydomain').

The implementation is like this one:

```
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
  {lang: 'es'}
</script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="https://mydomain"></div>
```

Some additional notes on this issue:

- This implementation is been working for years and with no changes we started to receive this console error.
- The error does not affect the correct behaviour of the Share Button.
- The error stops to be showed if, clicking the Share Button, the iFrame opens and I log into Google.
- If `<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="24" data-href="https://mydomain"></div>` is not placed on the DOM, the error stops to be shown.
- This situation happens on Mac/Windows and Chrome/Firefox/Edge... Safari seems to be an exception and works properly.

Is anyone having this same issue or does anyone have more information about it?

Comment: I reported it here: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/46#issuecomment-367508405

Comment: Thanks @mayrop , just checked your post.

Comment: This error can be ignored for now as it doesn't prevent normal functioning of the share button. We're investigating why this has started to be raised.